# Database backup taking issue

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

I am using Sql Server 2005.

I wanted to take back up of my database through simple sql command.

For this I referred [THIS](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/02/08/sql-server-backup-and-restore-database-using-command-prompt-sqlcmd/) document.

Made command as follows:

```
backup database webbasednewsoft to disk 'e:\wb.bak'
```

but its giving me error as:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'e:\wb.bak'.
```

I dont understand what is syntax error in this?

I have made everything according to doccument.

I thought the issue was for escape sequence, hence i also tried,

```
backup database webbasednewsoft to disk 'e:\\wb.bak'
```

But the error was same.

Please guid me for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an `=` sign.

```
 backup database webbasednewsoft to disk='e:\wb.bak'
```

[See here for the MSDN for the BACKUP command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx)

*And if you look at your reference it too mentions using an `=` sign! but hey we're all guilty of eager reading I know I do it... :-)*

Comment: Ohh, this worked, really a silly mistake. But i am not able to find .bak file on E:\ drive. what can be the problem?

Comment: It will be the E:\ on the DB server